# What is the difference between initializing a dictionary and declaring in Swift?

Tags: swift

Not sure if my title is accurate. Please comment if so will update.

In one method I just create the dictionary and initialize it with `()`

In the other I create it and immediately fill it with a key value pair.

What is the difference? Is one prefered over the other?

```
//initializing dictionary
var airPortCodesInitialize = [Int: String]()

//vs declaring
var airPortCodes: [String: String] = ["SLC": "Salt Lake City", "LAX": "Los Angeles"]
```

Comment: It is totally dependent on your requirement However There is no difference , This is two different syntax, Like we are doing in other programming language like Objective C , C ,C++.

Comment: Both forms declare **and** initialize the dictionary, once empty, once with a few default key value pairs. Side note: Generally you should not annotate types unless the compiler tells you to do.

Comment: In a nutshell, the part to the left of the `=` is the declaration. The part to the right of the `=` is the initialization. Though with Swift you can say that the type inference from the right side of the `=` could be considered part of the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, you are declaring a dictionary and initializing it. The only difference is that the first line creates an empty dictionary, the second line creates a dictionary filled with key value pairs.

A single declaration looks like this:

```
var myDictionary: [String: String]
```

I think you misunderstood what declarations are, so for the rest of this answer, I will compare the line above and your first line.

> What is the difference?

A single declaration gives the variable no value, so if you try to use `myDictionary` immediately after the declaration without initializing it, the compiler gives you an error:

```
print(myDictionary["Hello"]) // error
```

> Is one prefered over the other?

Most of the time, you should put the initialisation and declaration on the same line like you did in

```
var airPortCodesInitialize = [Int: String]()
```

This is more readable.

Sometimes though, you might want different initial values for a constant dictionary depending on a value. Then you must separate the declaration and initialisation:

```
let myConstantDict: [String: String]
switch something {
case .foo:
    myConstantDict = ...
case .bar:
    myConstantDict = ...
}
```

Comment: Great answer, very clear, and you helped point me in a better direction. Thanks.